# Using ShareKit 2.0 in a HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sharekit

I'm developing a HTML5-based iOS app with PhoneGap. I'm using the latest version of PhoneGap 2.2.0. I want to include a share button, so users can share a message on Facebook and Twitter. I did some research and found my way to ShareKit 2.0. I actually managed to complete the necessary steps described on the [wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). My project is able to build successfully. :)

From here on I'm stuck. I can't find anything how to implement this in my JavaScript (jQuery) project. The old ShareKitPlugin [describes a few steps](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ShareKitPlugin), but it doesn't work. So I guess it changed since 2.0.

Is there another tutorial of some kind I can follow? Or is there another solution to include Facebook and Twitter share buttons? What I like about the ShareKit plugin is that it uses the native FB/Twitter apps installed on your phone (if I am correct assuming this).

Comment: You shouldn't ever post a sentence like "it doesn't work" to Stack Overflow without describing how it doesn't work.  Do you get an error message?  Does it just not do anything?  Does your app hang?  Does it fail to share?

Comment: Indeed, I meant that it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the steps on the "Adding the Plugin to the Project" section on [phonegap plugin page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ShareKitPlugin)?

If so, after adding the ShareKitPlugin.js import at your html file, like this:

```
<script src="ShareKitPlugin.js"></script>
```

you just need to call the share method, like this:

```
window.plugins.shareKit.share("text that will be shared", "http://google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. I also had to change the User Header Search Paths.